# How to get user defined variables in command prompt like Tab is used to get items in current directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, window, shortcuts

I am having more that 10 command to run on [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd). I created variables for whole command. e.g

```
set create_unit=run -data -logfile=log.txt
set run_data= run -input=test.xml -output=Test.html
```

To run command I use `%create_unit%` but running this command I have to type whole variable. I want to know is there any way where I can use some key like tab to get available variable. Like If I type `%cre` in cmd after pressing required key I will get variable starting with specified text.

Comment: Why use an eleven character variable name then complain about having to type it all? If you use `set "cu=run -data -logfile=log.txt"`, then you could use it like this `%cu%`, which is exactly the same amount of typing as your suggestion of using `%cre`!

Comment: @Compo I agree you. If I find the way It will be good for me!

Comment: Out of curiosity,  would your variable commands be executing with variable values? I notice the 'command' `run_data=run -input=test.xml -output=Test.html` and find myself wondering what the point of hard coding commands with fixed values is. Depending on what your actually processing with these commands, it may be with your time to consider using substring modification or [batch macro's that accept arguments](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518&start=15)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `batch-file`?  Seems like you are doing everything from the command prompt.  Which in that case you could use doskey macros.

Comment: you can use Autohotkey to automate input

Comment: @MikhailV How ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Autohotkey to automate input.
For example I want to show the directory contents (`dir` command) by pressing Ctrl-Enter, I use this script:

```
#If winActive("ahk_exe cmd.exe") 

^enter::
    send {text}dir /O:G
    send {enter}
return
```

So you can directly bind shortcuts to any command.  But if you want to expand the text command by first letters (like the native Tab works) it will be more complicated, but still possible in some way.